# Prepending and overwriting a class with AJAX response in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a site that has like button attached to posts made by users. I want whenever a user likes a post, the like count of that post should be replaced with current one but it is affecting the whole post.

This is code for the Like button

```
echo "<span class = 'likecount'>". $likes . "</span><button class='mlike pacedown' 
 value='".$post_id."' name = 'like' type='submit'><span class = 'buttons'>Like</span>
 <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></span></button>";
```

And this the AJAX that gets fired whenever the button is clicked:

```
$(".mlike").click(function () {
    $(".murconform").submit(function(e){
        return false;
    });
    var post_id = $(this).val();
    var user_id = $(".user_id").text();
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "likes.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { post : post_id , user : user_id },
      dataType: "html"
    });
    request.done(function( msg ) {
    alert ("User ID is " + user_id + "  Post ID is " + post_id);              
        $('.likecount').html( msg ); 
    });
});
```

And this is the `echo` result from `likes.php` after update the database:

```
echo "<span class = 'likecount'>". $count . "</span>";
```

The database side is working just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by ".. affecting the whole post", what's going wrong exactly?

Comment: is there always only one .likecount element?

Comment: @Alex no. All the posts have same class.

Comment: make your span unique with id as <span id = 'likecount_'.$post_id></span>. then change its contents using $('#likecount_'.post_id).html('your data'). do not use $().replaceWith() function. echo $count; from your likes.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welll your are replacing the html inside the span with a `<span class = 'likecount'>` again.

why don't you just `echo $count` from you ajax called page and only this will be replaced in success function..

try this

in you likes.php file

```
 echo $count; //just return the count
```

no changes in ajax ..

```
//same
request.done(function( msg ) {
 alert ("User ID is " + user_id + "  Post ID is " + post_id);              
    $('.likecount').html( msg ); 
});
```

that should do the trick..

you can also change you datatype to JSON and send json as response in your php ..

**updated**

```
 $(".murconform").submit(function(e){
    return false;
 });

 $(".mlike").click(function () {
   var $this=$(this);
   var post_id = $(this).val();
   var user_id = $(".user_id").text();
   var request = $.ajax({
       url: "likes.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: { post : post_id , user : user_id },
       dataType: "html"
   });

   request.done(function( msg ) {
     alert ("User ID is " + user_id + "  Post ID is " + post_id);              
        $this.prev('.likecount').html( msg ); 
     });
   });
```

Comment: Still not working... Thinking of how I can prepend the result to button that fired the event and overwrite the existing class `.likecount`

Comment: then, you can use `replaceWith`  `$('.likecount').replaceWith( msg );`

Comment: caheck your developer tools  console tab.. what are you getting in msg...`console.log(msg)`

Comment: It seems you don't get me... If I click LIKE button of a post, it returns 1 but I have many post with their appropriate LIKE count displayed. And 1 that is returned replaces every other LIKE count with 1.

Comment: hmm i think i got you now...try with `this` reference and `prev()`.. so that it replaces only that likecount and not others.. `$this.prev('.likecount').html( msg ); ` ..updated my answer checkit out

Comment: Once again I have this problem and have posted but no answer yet. How do I target the second element in jQuery? Say, I click on 'More' button which is attached to every post with a class `.mmore`. Comments for every post are hidden under `div` with a class `.commentdata`. I want if you click on **More** of a particular post, only comment(s) for that post should appear but it all comments for the post are appearing...

Comment: `$( ".mmore" ).click(function() {
 var $this=$(this);
 $(".murconform").submit(function(e){
   return false;
  });
  $('.commentdata').slideToggle("slow");
 
});`